# How to unlock Non-Consumable InappPurchase automatically after restoring Previously completed Transactions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, in-app-purchase

I have developed a Non-Consumable InAppPurchase application. The App was rejected, apple point out that `We found that while your app offers In-App Purchase(s) that can be restored, it does not include the required "Restore" feature to allow users to restore the previously purchased In-App Purchase(s)`. So Now I have implemented `restoreCompletedTransactions` method in My application to restore the previously Completed Transactions.

The Code I have Implemented is

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked
{
      [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
```

All is working fine, But the Problem is When I Click on the button the InAppPurchases are Not Unlocking Automatically. It is again asking to buy the app by raising the alert that

[image]

If I Click on buy It is raising the alert that

[image]

By raising these alerts user May Confuse Because he/she already purchased those products But it again asking to buy(But he/she don't aware of the Next alert Message that you have already Purchased)..
So, My requirement is I don't want to raise these two alerts after restoring the transactions for previously purchased products. Directly the product should be unlocked. How can I do that...? Is it possible to do that..?

Comment: Thats just how `StoreKit` works until it verifies that the items have been purchased. It's unfortunate but this is normal behavior.

Comment: @WrightsCS Thank u for giving reply. But in this http://appotography.com/2011/07/06/restoring-purchases-on-iphone-and-ipad/ blog He gave that `Other apps have a feature called “Restore Purchases”. This may look confusing when you read it, but restoring simply re-downloads or unlocks all the content you have paid for, without having to go through the process of manually selecting several items and downloading them individually.` But Iam not getting idea to do that..? If u don't mind can u please tell me What is the Exact use of `restoreCompletedTransactions` method..